# How to get html element after append with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ckeditor

I found some JQuery solutions, but I am limited by school task restrictions to use pure Javascript, and I need to use specific early appended element that is still not in DOM for replacing by my CKEDITOR.

Code:

```
function newOption(){

     ...

     mainUL = document.getElementById("myUL");

     var inputA = document.createElement("input");
     inputA.type ="text";
     inputA.style = "margin-right: 45px";
     inputA.name = "option[]";
     inputA.id = inputID;

     mainUL.appendChild(inputA );

     CKEDITOR.replace(inputID).setData('Type anything you want ...');

     ...

}
```

By replacing my input with CKEDITOR will JS fail, because input, commonly, is still not in DOM. I tried to use

```
mainUL.innerHTML += "all elements like html text";
```

and this is working and will immediately insert elements into DOM, but I can't to use innerHTML, because it will remove old listeners (for example checked checkboxes that JS will set from checked to unchecked, what is my main problem due to I have to try using append DOM function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the code to wrap the call to `CKEDITOR.replace` in a `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  CKEDITOR.replace(inputID).setData('Type anything you want ...');
},0).
```

This will allow the browser time to insert the element before trying to replace it.

And I assume that `inputID` has a valid value in it...

Comment: Hmm, I thought that timeout will not work, but it works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: The problem often comes down to allowing the browser some time to do its thing before you do more. The `setTimeout` allows time for the browser and then calls the `setTimeout` function after.